# can i save script variable with rendered value?(django & HTML)

Tags: html, django

I am trying to make some example site and have some problems

what i want to do is save script variable with rendered value like this

```
var {{'rendered from template value'}} = .....
```

this is my some of codes

```
{% for coord in object_list %} 

            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng({{coord.x_coordinate  }},{{coord.y_coordinate}});
            var {{ coord.coordinate_name }} =  new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map});

 {% endfor %}
```

sorry for my poor explain and i hope to get some answers :D

Comment: Could you be more specific about what are you trying to achieve? It looks to me like all you need is a object/array that you could use to store the Marker, then you can use it later in your javascript. I don't think generating variable names using Django variables is a good idea.

Comment: @samu yeah i tried to make array marker[] and give index with coord.id which is DB's pk and it worked i just wonder it is possible to generate varibale with Django's rendered varibale   anyway thanks for your opinion